# How share text with image on WhatsApp and Facebook via Share dialog?

Tags: android, android-intent, share-intent

I want to share text with image on WhatsApp and Facebook, I did for **Whatsapp** but the issue is in **WhatsApp business** because of package **`com.whatsapp`** and **`com.whatsapp.w4b`** but how to set both at once, and facebook only sent image not text, so to resolve the issue, please.

My code for sharing via WhatsApp, Facebook, and Twitter.

```
private void share(String text, Uri uri, int type) {
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    share.setType("image/*");
    switch (type) {
        case 2:
            share.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
            break;
        case 3:
            share.setPackage("com.facebook.katana");
            break;
        case 4:
            share.setPackage("com.twitter.android");
            break;
        case 1:
        default:
            break;
    }
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Select"));
}
```

Comment: setPackage only support single package at time , so you need to work with a custom popup for sharing

Answer (score -1):

`share.setPackage("pakagename");`

is working for **whatsapp** and **twitter** but not for facebook so use facebook sdk .

Comment: yes but the issue is in facebook is hash key.. working in my device but not in other device i do not know.

Comment: `share.setPackage("com.facebook.katana")` for facebook or `share.setPackage("com.facebook.orca")` for messenger both work perfectly fine. Have no idea what you're talking about.